# C - Creating an array of strings dynamically (malloc)

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, malloc

For my homework, I would have to make an array of strings dynamically using malloc.
A I was not really capable to understand already available solutions as it had a slightly different way to use it than I want mine.

MY PROBLEM:
So, in short: I am making a text-based adventure game. The inventory should be "any-sized" said my professor. If the person has no items, then the inventory's size should be zero as well, with 1 item it should only contain 1 item, etc-etc.

I tried to make something to work, but I am not really capable to understand how malloc actually works, so here is my code (which is obviously incorrect, but how would it be correct to do what I want it to do?):

```
char* inventory;
int amount=0;
inventory=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*amount);
//NOW THERE SHOULD BE AN INVENTORY WITH SIZE ZERO SINCE AMOUNT=0
//NOW I WANT TO GIVE THE PLAYER AN ITEM:
amount++;
inventory=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(amount+1);
inventory[0]="sword";
//I WANT TO WRITE OUT INVENTORY TO TEST IF IT WORKS:
printf("%s", inventory[0]);
//FREE THE BITS LOCKED WITH MALLOC:
free(inventory);
```

Professor teaches us that we have to write amount+1 because of the last character of a string must be '\0' or something like that.

So, here is how I understand how malloc works (but maybe this is not how it works and I understand it incorrectly):
Normally, this is how would you create an array of strings for example:

```
char strings[10][200];
```

Which would mean that you have 10 strings, each can be 200 characters long.
When I use malloc as in my code:
The integer 'amount' is basically the same as the number 10 in my example, and the sizeof(char) is basically the same as the number 200 in my example, right?
If not, then I am totally lost.

Still, my code is not working obviously, so I would really-really appreciate some help from you guys, with working malloc C codes, and some explanations, if you have the time of course.

Comment: `with working malloc C codes`..nopes, not a chance. :)

Comment: In C, strings of unknown/dynamic length are represented by `char*` pointers to their first character. That pointer points to the beginning of the memory allocated by that string (+ trailing \0). To manage a number of dynamic strings, you'll need a number of `char*`, e.g. an array of those pointers. An array of pointers is again some memory space represented by a pointer to its first element. So, if you need an array of strings, the array could be declared as `char**` because it points to the first pointer (`char*`) to a string.

Comment: When I google the exact question, the first 8 results are all Stackoverflow questions on this topic. If you have already looked for solutions, and not found an exact answer, please examine these questions so you can understand the topic (make an array of strings dynamically using malloc), and develop your own solution.

Comment: Enable all warnings in your compiler and set it up so that they are treated as errors. With gcc or clang, use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror.

Comment: `last character of a string must be '\0' or something like that.` The last four words should not be there :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to do, but let us analyze your code:

```
char* inventory;
int amount=0;
inventory=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*amount);
```

You have just allocated zero bytes of memory since `amount` is zero. The documentation says "*If size is 0, malloc allocates a zero-length item in the heap and returns a valid pointer to that item*" so you have a valid pointer, but no storage.

```
amount++;
inventory=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(amount+1);
```

You have now allocated 2 bytes of storage. However, you have lost the storage you had just allocated, even though it is zero bytes, because you assigned the result of the second call to `malloc` to the variable that holds the result of the first call to `malloc`. You should have `free`d it before.

```
inventory[0]="sword";
```

This is invalid because `inventory` is a `char *`, so `inventory[0]` is a single `char`. Your compiler should have warned you, so turn warnings on.

```
printf("%s", inventory[0]);
```

The result of this printf call is undefined because you want a string to be printed but you pass only a single character.

```
free(inventory);
```

That is good, though you have lost the first allocation (see above).

From this analysis, I hope you can amend your code to do what you want.

Comment: "You assigned a pointer to a constant string to inventory[0]. However, inventory is just two bytes large" No, this is absolutely not what happens. `inventory[0]` *is not a pointer*, it is a `char`. This assignment is simply invalid and should provoke a diagnostic. Same thing about using `inventory[0]` in a printf

Comment: @n.m., I saw my mistake and fixed it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an array of strings (ie an array of arrays of `char`s), but you have a pointer to a `char`. In C, pointers and arrays are often interchangeable (though anyone saying that they're the same thing hasn't used C) — you can think of this because you can do arithmetic on a pointer to access adjacent data, and arrays are just stored as adjacent data. So you need a pointer to pointers to characters, or `char **`.

You need to think about exactly how your data is going to be stored in memory. In this case, you will want to have one inventory list that stores an array of pointers (pointers are fixed-length so this is fine). Each pointer will be a pointer to the actual string containing that item in the inventory.

Second, the inventory itself needs to be `malloc`'d, but if all of the strings you want to store in it are fixed at compile-time, the strings themselves don't have to be. If this is confusing to you, think of it this way — when you run the program it needs to be loaded into memory somewhere. So strings that were compiled into the program will exist somewhere in memory, and C will let you take a pointer to this string in memory just like you can take a pointer to variables in memory. So, every time you need to add a string to your inventory, you'll first want to resize your inventory by incrementing its size, creating a new inventory with the new size, using `memcpy` or similar to copy the existing contents of the inventory to the new copy, and then calling `free` on the old copy (very important otherwise you will get a memory leak, which are hard to spot but mean that if your program runs for long enough it will eventually eat all your RAM), before finally overwriting your pointer to the old copy with the pointer to the new copy.

Then, you'll want to put the string into the inventory by doing something like `inventory[amount-1] = "some string";` (of course, the string could also be passed into a function as an argument, in which case it should be a variable of type `char *`).

If your strings aren't all fixed at compile-time (ie if you want to put someone's name in the inventory that they enter on the command-line, or if you want to have a number like "thing 1", "thing 2" etc. that is generated in a loop or something), then you'll need to `malloc` space for the string as well.

Sorry if this is confusing, but this is really the sort of thing you need to be able to understand to be able to claim any sort of skill in C. This is a very brief explanation of quite a complex topic, so if you don't understand it, you seriously need to spend more time with more basic training materials to try to learn it. I'm not going to just give you the code for that reason (and also because it'd take more time than it's worth for me to write). You need to have a basic understanding of how pointers work and their relationship to arrays in C, and at least a vague understanding of  how this sort of thing is stored in memory (including the difference between the stack and the heap), in order to be able to solve this problem properly. Good luck!

Comment: I would like to thank you for your long and explaining answer. I will take my time now, as much as I need, to try to understand it as much as I can. I will give you a feedback about what was I able to accomplish with it. Thank you! Definite upvote from me for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can give a couple of tips:

- Use structs to group variables together (like array and array length)
- Use structs to create [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (example: 'inventory' data type)
- Create functions for common operation (initialize inventory, print inventory, grow inventory capacity, add to inventory, free inventory, ...)
- Don't bother (ever) with string slices, [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) and 2D arrays unless absolutely necessary. A array of character pointers works just fine in this case. (Don't think you were planning to implement this but I'll mention it anyway)
- However, you might possible want to create an `inventory_item` struct in the future, instead of just storing char pointers. This way you could add other item attributes like count and quality. (`"You have %d %s, it is %s", item.count, item.name, item.quality`)

Refactoring your code:

```
struct inventory {
    size_t num_items; // What you call `amount`.
    char **items; // What you call `inventory`. Note that it's a pointer to a _character pointer_, as the other answers indicated.
};

int main(void) {
    struct inventory inv;

    // Initialize the inventory.
    // You might want to create a function for this.
    // In C++, you would use constructors.
    inv.num_items = 0;
    inv.items = NULL; // Set `items` to NULL, see below at realloc

    // Once again, you might want to create a function for this,
    // since you'll probably end up doing this a lot
    void *old; // Store the old inv.items; in case we fail to allocate a new one.
    old = inv.items;
    inv.items = realloc(inv.items, sizeof(*inv.items) * inv.num_items+1);
    // Explaination: `ptr = realloc(ptr, size)` is the same as `new_ptr = malloc(size); memcpy(ptr, old_ptr, /* size of old_ptr */); free(old_ptr);`
    // realloc works the same as malloc when it's first argument is NULL.
    if (!inv.items) { // Failed to allocate memory.
        free(old); // Deinitialize the inventory. A `goto fail;` would be useful here.
        return 1;
    }
    // Maybe you'd want seperate functions for adding items and growing the array, then call the growth function here.
    inv.items[inv.num_items] = "sword";
    inv.items++;

    // Print the inventory
    for (size_t i=0; i < inv.num_items; i++) {
        printf("inventory[%lu] = %s\n", i, inv.items[i]); // %lu = unsigned long, `size_t` on my system.
    }

    // You might again want a function for this
    free(inv.items); // Deinitialize the inventory
     // Optional, but cleaner:
    inv.items = NULL;
    inv.num_items;

    return 0;
}
```

The disadvantage to the above approach is that you cannot mix string literals and allocated ones because you wouldn't know which one's to `free` when de-initializing. (`free` on a string literal is undefined behavior).

Should be fine if all your items are string literals, though. This way you could also safely use the `==` operator on these strings. Note though that if you ever find yourself being able to safely use the `==` operator on strings, you probably want to define an enum.

How I would write it (Won't explain in depth):

```
typedef struct inventory inv_t;
typedef struct inventory_item inv_item_t;

struct inventory {
    size_t num_items;
    inv_item_t items;
};
struct inventory_item {
    int type;
};

// Convenience macro for grouping enum data
#define GENERATE_ITEM_TYPES(XX) \
XX(ITEM_NONE, "<unknown item>") \
XX(ITEM_SWORD, "sword")

enum inventory_type {
#define XX(enumname, ignore) enumname,
    GENERATE_ITEM_TYPES(XX)
#undef XX
    NUM_ITEMS, // Automatically equals 2
};
static char *names[NUM_ITEMS] = {
#define XX(ignore, strname) strname,
    GENERATE_ITEM_TYPES(XX)
#undef XX
};

static int inv_init(inv_t *self);
static int inv_fini(inv_t *self);

static int inv_print(inv_t *self);

static int inv_reserve(inv_t *self, size_t new_size);

static int inv_add(inv_t *self, inv_type_t type);

static inv_item_t inv_item_from_type(int type) {
    inv_item_t item = { .type = type };
    return item;
}

int main(void)
{
    inv_t inv;

    if (inv_init(&inv) != 0) goto fail;

    if (inv_add(&inv, inv_item_from_type(ITEM_SWORD)) != 0) goto fail;
    if (inv_print(&inv) != 0) goto fail;

    inv_fini(&inv);

    return 0;

fail:
    inv_fini(&inv);

    return 1;
}

static int inv_init(inv_t *self)
{
    self->num_items = 0;
    self->items = NULL;

    return 0;
}
static int inv_fini(inv_t *self)
{
    free(self->items);
    self->items = NULL;
    self->num_items;

    return 0;
}

static int inv_print(inv_t *self)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < inv.num_items; i++) {
        printf("inventory[%llu] = %s\n", (unsigned long long int)i, names[inv.items[i]]); // No format for size_t, so convert to unsigned long long and use format `%llu`. More portable.
    }
}

static int inv_reserve(inv_t *self, size_t new_size)
{
    void *old;

    old = inv.items;
    inv.items = realloc(inv.items, sizeof(*inv.items) * new_size);
    if (!inv.items) goto fail;

    return 0;

fail:
    free(old);
    return 1;
}
static int inv_add(inv_t *self, char *item)
{
    if (inv_reserve(self, inv.num_items + 1) != 0) return 1;

    inv.items[inv.num_items++] = item;

    return 0;
}
```